# wpdb Query to join posts and post meta

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Im trying to select post title and two metafield values.But i cant get the correct query.Y query is pasted below please help.

```
$querystr = "
                SELECT $wpdb->posts.post_title 
                FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
                WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
                AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = side_post_meta_id 
                AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE %".$search_term."%
                AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = side_post_id
                AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE %".$cat_find."%                   
                AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
                ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,10
             ";
             print_r($querystr);
             $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . At a minimum, please provide your table structure, your desired results, and the actual results.

Comment: This is a question regarding WordPress, so he doesn't need to provide table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this...

```
<?php
    global $wpdb; 
    $get_results= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT p.post_title, pm2.meta_value , pm3.meta_value   
                    FROM wp_posts as p
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm1 ON pm1 .post_id = p.ID

    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm2 ON pm2 .post_id = p.ID AND pm2.meta_key='side_post_meta_id' AND pm2.meta_value like '%$search_term%'

    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm3 ON pm3 .post_id = p.ID AND pm3 .meta_key='side_post_id' AND pm3 .meta_value like '%$cat_find%'

    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'post' ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,10");

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($get_results);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: What is the OP's problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: then you can give me a solution as you  know what is the problem

Comment: I don't understand your reply.